# Reactjs fetch as google blank

Tags: reactjs, google-search-console

Actually, I do not know why my site is blank in google fetch render.
I am using react router 4 and webpack 4 to build file.

Here is my webpack:

```
  mode:'production', //production //development
  entry: "./src/app.js",     
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: "/",
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot: true
  },
```

And here is my app file:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,
    withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Detail from '../components/Detail';
import Blog from '../components/Blog';
import Popular from '../components/Popular';
import Categories from '../components/Categories';
import Feature from '../components/feature';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Category from '../components/Category';
import Page from '../components/Page';
import Search from '../components/Search';
import Register from '../components/Register';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import $ from 'jquery';

//Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; 
import store from './store';
```

Can everyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the "ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));" that is responsible for inject the main component to your index page?

Comment: @LeonardoLobato I just do not understand why babel-polyfill not working although i added it